# aes_ctr_128_encrypt in Android using boringSSL

Tags: android, encryption, aes, boringssl

I am trying to implement aes_ctr128_encrypt in android using BoringSSL as defined by google.

I built the application with CMAKE and Gninja by following the link

https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/master/BUILDING.md

Now I have crypto and ssl folders in the build folder but there is no AES definition in any of the files as AES.h was in the include folder in root directory.

Anyhow, The binaries thus generated with CMAKE are also giving .a files and not .so files. How can I use those .a files in my project to access the aes_ctr_128_encrypt?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I'm trying to do the same thing...

Comment: yes, you can do this with by selecting the algorithm from here [Inline Link] (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography) then starting with the IV of all 0's and then changing the IV for each block as you are encrypting.